# return the keys of a multikey dict if sum equal a given integer in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have a dict in below:

```
d={(0, 'A', 1): 1, (1, 'A', 1): 2, (0, 'B', 1): 4, (1, 'B', 2): 5}
```

I am trying to write an efficient code to return the key(s) if the sum of the values equal to a given integer value. For example, in the above dict, I wanna find the keys that the sum of their values is equal 3. So, the code should return `(0, 'A', 1)` and `(1, 'A', 1)`.

One way is just to loop over the items of my dict and check the sums, but I think there must be a better way for it. Here is what i have got so far:

```
def findPair(A, sum):
    # create an empty dictionary
    dict = {}

    for i, (key, value) in enumerate(A.items()):

        # check if pair `(e, sum - e)` exists

        # if the difference is seen before, print the pair
        if sum - value in dict:
            print("Pair found", (dict.get(sum - value), i))
            return

        # store index of the current element in the dictionary
        dict[i] = value

    # No pair with the given sum exists in the list
    print("Pair not found")
```

Comment: `One way is just to loop over the items...`: Post what you've tried so far so that we can comment on it.

Comment: should you get one or all combinations which gives desired sum?

Comment: Sum of how  many keys? In the example, sum of values for `(0, 'A', 1)` and `(1, 'A', 1)` are 3, Is it always the case of sum of values for two keys? And what if there are multiple such combinations? I think it belongs to some sort of combination problem.

Comment: @ex4 all the combinations that gives the sum.

Comment: @Selcuk Just added my code. Thanks!

Comment: @ThePyGuy No it can be only one key, or a combination of keys.

Comment: @armin I don't see anything wrong with your code, except for it doesn't check for the "only one key" condition you mentioned in a comment above. Why are you not happy with it?